# How to compute the convolution of two functions which diverge at infinity?

Tags: convolution

How to compute the convolution of two functions which diverge at infinity?

e.g. $e^{x^2}*e^{x^4}$

We can't directly write as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t^2}e^{(x-t)^4}~dt$ or $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(x-t)^2}e^{t^4}~dt$ as both integrals are divergent.

Comment: 1. View the two functions as distributions,.
2. Compute their Fourier transforms. These are also distributions.
3. Try to multiply them. If you can't, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a matter of "computing": the question is, what do you mean by "convolution" in a case such as this?